# EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI

Tags: eclipse-rcp, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, jboss-eap-6, ejb-3.2

I am running Eclipse RCP, EJB3 and Jboss EAP 6.3

**Working** - When I run my RCP application from Eclipse launch option with remote JBoss configuration and EJB lookup.

**Requirement** - When I do export RCP product and launch it is not able to lookup  remote EJB bean. The same code which is working in eclipse IDE.

**EJB lookup URL format:**

```
ejb:/remoteApp//Bean!org.jboss.as.stateless.RemoteCalculator
```

**Code where getting error message:**

```java
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://10.10.10.10:4447");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "userAdmin");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "userAdmin#1");

        Context context = new InitialContext(properties);

        Object returnValue = context.lookup(jndi);  // throw exception at this line
```

**Note:** I have configured all other configuration properly because it is working in local environment (i.e. Eclipse with all datasource and JBoss user/pwd settings). Need to know how I can lookup the EJB beans from exported RCP product.

Comment: Can you provide the exception stack trace and remote EJB source code?

Comment: jndi = ejb:GeoProject/GeoEJB//GeoElementsBean!com.abc.net.ejb.IGeoElementsRemoteBean

Comment: The above mentioned jndi is working fine in eclipse local environment with same jboss eap 6.3 server . While deploying EJB project on Dev  jboss eap 6.3 server lookup is not working.

Comment: I think there's something missing in your code snippet. Can you provide a more complete version of that code?